# How can I put slider element inside link component from react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, swiper.js

I have that code:

```
<Link to="/movie/" key={item.id}>
  <SwiperSlide className="swiper-slider-card">
    <LoadImage
      path={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + item.poster_path}
      altImage="backgroundSliderImage"
      classNames="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-contain"
    />
    <div className="absolute bottom-2 left-3">
      <p className="text-white text-2xl bg-slate-600 inline-block p-2 rounded-lg  text-bold font-quicksand">
        {MovieDate}
      </p>
      <p className="text-2xl text-white mt-2 bg-slate-700 p-2 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md">
        {item.title}
      </p>
    </div>
  </SwiperSlide>
</Link>
```

but when I'm clicking on swiper element it doesn't redirect me to `"/movie/"` it is also not visible in devtools

I don't know why, maybe swiper remove that element or don't identify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use swiper in the outermost layer. I'm leaving an example code for you:

```
    <Swiper
  spaceBetween={50}
  slidesPerView={3}
  className="swiper-slider-card"}
>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
  ...
</Swiper>
```

Comment: i have swiper outer element, inside of it i'm rendering swiperslide element from array, which should contain link element, on click

Comment: It seems that the issue in your code is related to trying to use the Link component from react-router-dom to wrap a SwiperSlide component. The Link component is intended to wrap interactive elements such as buttons or anchor tags, and it may not work as expected when wrapping non-interactive elements like SwiperSlide.

To resolve this issue, you can attach an onClick event to the SwiperSlide component and use the useHistory hook from react-router-dom to programmatically navigate to the desired route.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the case that any click/mouse/pointer events within the `SwiperSlide` component are intercepted and handled, and ***don't*** propagate further up the DOM to the link to effect any navigation actions. Move the `Link` component down the ReactTree so that it's the child of `SwiperSlide` and still a parent of the UI content you want to interact with.

```
<SwiperSlide className="swiper-slider-card" key={item.id}>
  <Link to="/movie/">
    <LoadImage
      path={"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + item.poster_path}
      altImage="backgroundSliderImage"
      classNames="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-contain"
    />
    <div className="absolute bottom-2 left-3">
      <p className="text-white text-2xl bg-slate-600 inline-block p-2 rounded-lg  text-bold font-quicksand">
        {MovieDate}
      </p>
      <p className="text-2xl text-white mt-2 bg-slate-700 p-2 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md">
        {item.title}
      </p>
    </div>
  </Link>
</SwiperSlide>
```

Note that you may need to apply CSS to the `Link` to style (*or **un-style***) it visually.

[image: Edit i-cannot-put-slider-element-inside-link-component-from-react-router-dom]

Comment: yeah i did it and it worked, thank's for that